# EF Core 6 Generating faulty SQL for interpolated stored procedures using SqlParameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a SQL Server stored procedure with multiple parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BUP_BankUpload]
    @SPP_ProcessID uniqueidentifier,  
    @SPP_FileName NVARCHAR(250) = '',  
    @SPP_UploadInputType int,   
    @SPP_UploadOutputType int,  
    @SPP_CheckPreviousProcessing bit = 0,  
    @SPP_BankPeriod NVARCHAR(100) = '',  
    @SPP_BankName NVARCHAR(50) = 'Option'
```

I am calling it via EF Core 6 using `SqlParameter` and an interpolated query:

```
    SqlParameter[] sqlParams =
    {
          new SqlParameter("SPP_ProcessID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) { Value = Guid.NewGuid() },
          new SqlParameter("SPP_FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = bankFileName },
          new SqlParameter("SPP_UploadInputType", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1 },
          new SqlParameter("SPP_UploadOutputType", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1 },
          new SqlParameter("SPP_CheckPreviousProcessing", SqlDbType.Bit) { Value = true },
          new SqlParameter("SPP_BankPeriod", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = bankPeriod != null ? bankPeriod : "None"},
          new SqlParameter("SPP_BankName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = bankName}
    };

List<BankUploadModel>  BankUploadSQL = applicationDbContext.BankUpload.FromSqlInterpolated($"BUP_BankUpload {sqlParams[0]}, {sqlParams[1]}, {sqlParams[2]}, {sqlParams[3]}, {sqlParams[4]}, {sqlParams[5]}, {sqlParams[6]}").ToList();
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'BUP_BankUpload @SPP_ProcessID, @SPP_FileName, @SPP_UploadInputType, 
@SPP_UploadOutputType, @SPP_CheckPreviousProcessing, @SPP_BankPeriod, @SPP_BankName',
N'@SPP_ProcessID uniqueidentifier,@SPP_FileName nvarchar(65),@SPP_UploadInputType int,@SPP_UploadOutputType int,
@SPP_CheckPreviousProcessing bit,@SPP_BankPeriod nvarchar(4),@SPP_BankName nvarchar(5)',
@SPP_ProcessID='87DD543E-64F1-4C7A-A35B-82441B034B15',
@SPP_FileName=N'Processed_txns20060198-29Jan2022-05Feb2022_Final_(01-02-2022).csv',
@SPP_UploadInputType=1,
@SPP_UploadOutputType=1,
@SPP_CheckPreviousProcessing=1,
@SPP_BankPeriod=N'None',
@SPP_BankName=N'Bank1'
```

Which, when run, throws the following error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BUP_BankUpload, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Error converting data type nvarchar to date.

Which is impossible because there is no conversion of string to date in the stored procedure.

When I modify the SQL statement by removing the parameterization metadata as follows:

```
exec sp_executesql N'BUP_BankUpload 
@SPP_ProcessID=''87DD543E-64F1-4C7A-A35B-82441B034B15'',
@SPP_FileName=N''Processed_txns20060198-29Jan2022-05Feb2022_Final_(01-02-2022).csv'',
@SPP_UploadInputType=1,
@SPP_UploadOutputType=1,
@SPP_CheckPreviousProcessing=1,
@SPP_BankPeriod=N''None'',
@SPP_BankName=N''Bank1'''
```

With the same parameters, it works correctly.

Can anybody point me in the right direction as to what is going on here?,

Comment: Those calls are equivalent, and there are no datetime parameters.  The error is coming from inside the stored procedure, perhaps an execution plan difference or a difference in the session language that affects date formatting.

Comment: When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth. If SQL Server is telling you a conversion to `date` is failing while executing the sproc, then most probably a conversion to `date` is failing, and you haven't convinced me of the impossibility of this. Consider also *implicit* conversions (like copying from one table to another). While there is no apparent mechanism to explain why the different invocations expose the problem, that's a secondary concern. Debug the failing invocation first before moving on to that.

Comment: There is no date conversion. If I remove the entire contents of the stored procedure and leave a print statement, I get the same error.

Comment: Also the calls cannot be equivalent as one works and one does not.

Comment: I suggest you pass the parameters by name rather than position `$"BUP_BankUpload @SPP_ProcessID={sqlParams[0]}, @SPP_FileName={sqlParams[1]},` if it doesn't solve this error at least it will prevent future errors when the inevitable rewrite of the procedure happens by a later developer

Comment: The point of using a parameter array in this way is to avoid potential mismatches as they can be passed in any order as long as they are all there. Passing by name introduces the very problem we are trying to avoid.

Comment: You could check against each `sqlParam.Name` perhaps. No you cannot pass them in any order: there is no correlation between the parameter names on the stored procedure and the names of your parameters, because you are sending them as an ad-hoc batch. If you sent it as `CommandType.StoredProcedure` then it would work in any order, but not sure if you can do that with EF.

Comment: It fails even if the procedure body is empty? Then you've got something interesting indeed. Certainly I [cannot reproduce it the obvious way](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=29966dd09ab9c35b565c32961ef45891).